# Javascript ternary operator result always the same

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operator-keyword, ternary

The code below always responds with "hi". Even if i set the campaign1 variable to 0. Can anyone advise if I am writing this out incorrectly?

```js
campaign1 = 2;

campaign_string = (typeof campaign1 > 1 ? "hello" : "hi" );
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Why are you using `typeof` to fetch the *value* of a variable?

Comment: Well `typeof campaign1` is always `"number"` regardless of which numerical value you give it.

Comment: In my code later on I am concatenating a string with the variable campaign_string. Is there a better way to do this? As i can't use an if statement in my string concat.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `typeof` operator. Try repeating without that; and get rid of the unnecessary paranthesis too.

This should do

```
campaign1 = 2;

campaign_string = campaign1 > 1 ? "hello" : "hi";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `typeof` but not comparing it to a type. I think you mean to do this.

```
campaign1 = 2;

campaign_string = (campaign1 > 1 ? "hello" : "hi" );
```

`typeof` is used like this.

```
var variable = 'Test';

typeof variable === 'string' // This is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this 'typeof', so change it to:

```
campaign1 = 2;

campaign_string = campaign1 > 1 ? "hello" : "hi" );
```